# root directory in asp.net need not hard code

Tags: c#, asp.net

i am tryin to send mail to a user and providing him a authetication link to activate his account but i am hard coding the link. is there any way where i need not hard code

```
string url = "http://localhost:3876/User/Authenticate-User.aspx?emailID=" + emailfield;

string msgBody = "<h3>Dear User</h3>" + "<p>Thanks for your interest, Kindly click on the URL below to authenticate</p><br>" +
                              "<a href='" + url + "'>Activate Link</a><br><br>" +
                              "\r\n<p>With Regards,<br>Team</p>";
```

Comment: So whats the problem. You are generating ActivateLink dynamically I guess. If the same message is to be sent to every user then it is ok. How you want it to be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
string ActivationLink=Request.Url.ToString().Substring(0, Request.Url.ToString().LastIndexOf('/')) + "/Authenticate-User.aspx?emailID=" + emailfield;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!! both the answer worked up voted for both thanks

Comment: Just need to make sure the file generating ActivationLink is in same folder as Authenticate-User.aspx. Use Server.MapPath otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the correct address for where a page is hosted using Request.Url

I find the "GetComponents" method most flexible in that you can see your options with Intellisense quite easily.

```
string serverAddress = "http://" + 
HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.GetComponents(UriComponents.Host, UriFormat.SafeUnescaped);
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.GetComponents(UriComponents.Port, UriFormat.SafeUnescaped))) {
    serverAddress = serverAddress + ":" + HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.GetComponents(UriComponents.Port, UriFormat.SafeUnescaped);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!! both the answer worked up voted for both thanks